# Problema com responsividade bootstrap

Tags: html, html5, layout-responsivo

Estou tendo problemas para alinhar a responsividade do meu painel. Aqui uma imagem de como ele fica em telas grandes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas se eu diminuo um pouco a tela ele se embaralha dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo o trecho do código `HTML` da página onde eu cito essa parte. Eu to fazendo algo errado? Como posso corrigir isso?

```
<div class="right_col" role="main">
        <!-- top tiles -->
        <div class="row tile_count">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
            <span class="count_top">
              <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Ouvintes Únicos</span>
            <div class="count">37</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
            <span class="count_top">
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i> Marcações de Favoritos</span>
            <div class="count">14</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
            <span class="count_top">
              <i class="fa fa-play"></i> Contagem de Plays</span>
            <div class="count green">146</div>
            <span class="count_bottom">
              <i class="green">
                <i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>34% </i> From last Week</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
            <span class="count_top">
              <i class="fa fa-users"></i> Recados no Mural</span>
            <div class="count">4</div>
            <!-- <span class="count_bottom"><i class="red"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>12% </i> From last Week</span> -->
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Modifique a classe "col-sm-4" para col-sm-6

Comment: Hunter se possível coloque o CSS que usou para customizar a barra, sem ele é impossível simular seu erro

Comment: Se lembro-me bem, Bootstrap trabalha com 12 colunas, mas você definiu 4 elementos que ocupam 4 colunas cada (isso daria 16 colunas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa entender a ideia principal dos [grids](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vamos as siglas:

-`sm`: Small(Pequeno) - dispositivos com tamanho de tela maior que 576 pixels

-`md`: Medium(Médio) - dispositivos com tamanho de tela maior que 768 pixels

-`lg`: Large(Grande) - dispositivos com tamanho de tela maior que 992 pixels

-`xl`: Extra large(Super Grande) - dispositivos com tamanho de tela maior que 1200 pixels

Sempre que você insere uma nova div de coluna, você utiliza uma das classes de tamanho por exemplo `col-md-2` que diz que a div ocupará 2 colunas quando o dispositivo for Medium(tablets ou monitores super pequenos), lembre-se que o sistema de grid pode ter até 12 colunas por linha.

Para resolver o seu problema altere o `col-sm-4` para `col-sm-6` sendo assim a sua div ocupará 6 colunas em dispositivos mobile ou seja terá 2 divs por linha, se você quiser que cada div fique em uma linha basta colocar `col-sm-12` e assim por diante.

Comment: Sua explicação abriu minha cabeça sobre entender o conceito de sm, md e afins. Porém mesmo alterando continua a mesma coisa. Eu posso ter setado algo errado antes que interfere nesse trecho ou não?

Comment: @hunterxhunter qual o seu objetivo? vc quer que fique 4 na mesma ou que fique 2 em cada linha?

Answer (score 0):

O bootstrap tem um grelha de 12 colunas, quando reduz a resolução é aplicada a classe .col-em-4 que significa que vai ocupar o espaço de 4 colunas.

Como você está a utilizar 4x será equivalente 4x4 ou seja 16 colunas portanto mais 4 colunas acima do limite.

Tente colocar .col-sm-3 3x4 = 12

Verifique a documentação do Grid do bootstrap